# Run js script after angular is done rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I'm stuck in running js script after angular complete rendering. I cloned code from https://github.com/codrops/AnimatedHeader

I need it to run after html renders because it needs header element but as I'm developing an angularJs application and it takes some time to render so my scripts renders earlier and gives me error. So there is any way I can make it wait.

I have already tried using custom directive, using ng-cloak, putting my js in window.onload. I have tried many solutions but none worked for me.

**Here is my index.html:**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="pliro" ng-cloak="">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css
    </head>
    <body id="page-top" class="index">
        <script src="scripts/main/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/main/main-controller.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/header/header-controller.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/footer/footer-controller.js"></script>
        </script>
        <div ng-include="'scripts/header/header.html'"></div>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <div ng-include="'scripts/footer/footer.html'"></div>
    </body>

    <script ng-src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script ng-src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
</html>
```

I need classie.js and cbpAnimatedHeader.js to run after header.html renders.
Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it would help us if you include some of your personal code that relates to this issue. not just the github repo

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: FYI you have some markup issues in your sample HTML, missing tags, extra tags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Those two js are less then 100 line. 
I suggest you to re-write it into directive or service. They would not spend more then one day for you.

or

load all js at the end of body. Add `<script>` with loop check if "header.html" has been loaded, then load other js natively. I believe this is far more complex then above option.